# AWS Toolkit for .NET won't open in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded the AWS Tookkit for .NET a couple weeks ago and it was working fine.

http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/

For the last couple of days, I have not been able to open it in either Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012.

I have already uninstalled it, rebooted, and re-installed (multiple times)

I can choose it from the View menu, but when I select it, nothing happens.

I'm just looking for some direction to see what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: My first thoughts are what has changed? Have you had a Windows update? Have you installed anything in Visual Studio? Are there any errors being logged in Event Viewer. I'm assuming you're using a Windows OS.

Comment: Nothing has changed.  A co-worker of mine has the same build and service pack level and his is working.

Comment: Is there anything in Event Viewer / Event logs that may give you any clues? NB: I haven't used the AWS toolkit but I've got Visual Studio 2010 on my machine so if we don't find anything in your Event Viewer then I'll download it and see what I can learn for you.

Comment: If your co-worker's project is in source control then what happens when you check out his project?

Comment: The AWS kit would work independent of the solution.  If I just launch and instance of Visual Studio, I should be able to bring up the AWS Toolkit.  I will check the even viewer to see if it is throwing an issue.

Comment: The toolkit writes logs files to the directory C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\logs\vs2010.  My advice is to shutdown all instances of visual studio, clear this folder than restart visual studio and then select View->AWS Explorer.  After that check the log file to see if any errors help explain the issue.

Comment: Quite odd, I cannot find a folder at that path.  I'm going to continue looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to uninstall the Toolkit, then  go to the profile on the PC and delete the whole AWSToolkit folder, finally I re-installed it.  It allowed me to bring it back up and and browse everything.

Specifically, you want to delete the folder found at: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit`

Comment: Specifically, you want do delete the folder found at: 
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit