# AWS Explorer not present in VS 2012 after installing AWS Toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services

My set up is VS 2012 Web Developer Express on Win 7.
After installing AWS Toolkit for .Net 1.5, I cant find AWS Explorer in VIEW menu of VS 2012, but I can in VS 2010 Shell(which got installed with VS 2012).
Other points:
I installed the Toolkit while VS 2012 was still running. So I thought that could be a problem and I uninstalled and reinstalled it, but with no luck.
Looked at answers/suggestions to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259051/aws-toolkit-for-net-wont-open-in-visual-studio) but that doesnt solve my problem.

How should I get about it? Does AWS Toolkit install on Web Developer Express at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The licensing on the Express editions of Visual Studio unfortunately does not permit installation of 3rd party plugins. The toolkit needs an edition of 'standard' or higher.

Regards.

Comment: Oh damn it! Why would they do that? M$