# AWS Explorer not visible in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to install AWS toolkit on MS Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition) using the link [here](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/), but I can't find AWS Explorer in VIEW menu of VS:

[image: Screenshot showing absence of 'AWS Explorer' option]

Tried a couple of workarounds, such as in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259051/aws-toolkit-for-net-wont-open-in-visual-studio), but could not find a solution. Tried reinstalling the AWS toolkit and Visual studio as well.

Additional Info: I have installed Visual Studio in D drive, while the AWS Toolkit is installed in the default directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET
```

Answer (score 3):

You can download a preview version of the toolkit for Visual Studio 2017. It works as a charm in the released Community Edition. Use this link to get it: [Download AWS SDK extension to VS 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/preview-of-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio-2017/)

This is an VS extension, and it will link to - as Collin M. Barrett so rightly pointed out - to the actual AWS SDK for Net (Visual Studio).

Comment: Ugh, how pointlessly obnoxious on Amazon's part - the official page for the toolkit at https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/ offers no hint whatsoever that it doesn't support the current version on Visual Studio, and the installer happily proceeds and says that the toolkit is installed successfully. I would've had no clue what I was doing wrong without this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The toolkit is actually here: https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/ (What you are linking to is the SDK.) And, I don't think they have a release available for Visual Studio 2017 yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tool -> Extension and Updates -> Just Enable the AWS tool kit if it is installed